# adding margin to css causes some unwanted behavior

Tags: html, css, navigation

I wrote following html page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<title>Jenware | Personalized Gifts</title>
<style type="text/css">


/* styles for navigation */
#nav {
    background-color: #2322ff;
    height: 3em;
}
#nav ul {
    list-style:none;
    margin: 0 auto;     
        width: 19.5em; 
} 
#nav ul li {
    font-weight: normal;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        float:left;

}

 #nav ul li a {     
  display: block;   
  padding: .5em;    
  border: 1px solid #ba89a8; 
  border-radius: .5em;  
  margin: .25em; 
}    




</style>

</head>

<body>

<div id="nav">
<ul>
<li><a href="">House</a></li>
<li><a href="">Baby</a></li>
<li><a href="">More</a></li>
<li><a href="">About</a></li>
</ul>
</div>


<!-- end #content -->
</body>
</html>
```

and the output is followin[image]g

I made a small change in the section

```
 #nav ul li a {     
  display: block;   
  padding: .5em;    
  border: 1px solid #ba89a8; 
  border-radius: .5em;  
  margin: .5em; 
}
```

changed the margin from .25em to .5 em and now it appears as following

[image]
If you see the about thing has come out, I am not clear as what thing has caused this behaviour, just by changing margin how can this happen?

as per suggestions below I tried changing 
 if I remove the width column, and   in case I remove the float:left column then all the boxes are vertical
i.e.if I do

```
#nav ul {
    list-style:none;
    margin: 0 auto;     

} 
#nav ul li {
    font-weight: normal;
        text-transform: uppercase;

}
```

it comes as following
[image]

why is this happening

Comment: What did you expect to happen?

Comment: Try changing the width of the `ul`....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `#nav ul` element has a width of 19.5em.

Your `#nav ul li a` elements have 0.5em padding and 0.5em margin. Width-wise this adds up to 2em + 2px (border) *per element*. This means that the 4 of your elements have 8em + 8px width *without* any text.

This allows a total of 11.5em width to contain the text found within your elements. If the cumulative text exceeds 11.5em then your elements will *wrap* onto the next line.

To fix this, simply increase the width of your `#nav ul` element:

```css
#nav ul {
    width: 25em; /* Adjust accordingly. */
}
```

Comment: Ok if I remove the width column, I observe that all the boxes shift left , in case I remove the float:left column then all the boxes are vertical

Answer (score 0):

That's because your `#nav ul` has a fixed width `width: 19.5em`.

Now if you change the `width` or `padding` or `margin` of the inside `li` elements you need to change the total widht of your `ul`.

Answer (score 0):

By adding margin to your  tags, you've increased the overall width of the elements inside of the , but you've still got your  restricted to 19.5em.

You can either remove the width declaration from your  or increase its width.

Answer (score 0):

it's because the content is wider than the width of the containing element. adjust it so:

```
#nav ul {
  list-style:none;
  margin: 0 auto;     
  width: 19.5em; <- change this to 21em
}
```

on an aside, why not use html5  element instead of a div with an ID?

Comment: ok I updated the question I removed the margin and float also

Answer (score 0):

When you double your margin in EM, it will go passed the width that you have for the entire `nav`. Also, you have `float:left` hidden in your CSS. I would suggest getting rid of the `float:left` and doing `display:inline-block` instead, like so.

```
#nav {
background-color: #2322ff;
height: 3em;
}
#nav ul {
display: inline-block; 
list-style:none;
margin: 0 auto;     
} 
#nav ul li {
display: inline-block; 
font-weight: normal;
text-transform: uppercase;
}

#nav ul li a {     
display: inline-block;   
padding: .5em;    
border: 1px solid #ba89a8; 
border-radius: .5em;  
margin: .25em; 
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="nav">
<ul>
<li><a href="">House</a></li>
<li><a href="">Baby</a></li>
<li><a href="">More</a></li>
<li><a href="">About</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Ok if I remove the width column, I observe that all the boxes shift left , in case I remove the float:left column then all the boxes are vertical

Answer (score 0):

The only changes you must to do is to apply this css agains you have:

```
#nav ul {
  display: block; 
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
}
#nav ul li {
  display: inline-block; 
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```